# how to create a log file at the same time to run a batch file in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a batch file and it is running okay but i want to store output of the same batch file at the same time into a separate file on a location.

File is created successfully but there is no content in this file.

I am trying following command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root -p12345 db1552 < C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\script.txt > C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\mysqllog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

tuesday001.sql (generates a resultset):

```
use stackoverflow;
select qId,title from questions_mysql order by qId desc limit 10;
```

tuesday001.sql (generates no resultset):

```
use stackoverflow;
use so_gibberish;
use stackoverflow;
```

Test:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root -p < C:\nate\tuesday001.sql > C:\nate\tuesday001_out.txt
Enter password: ********

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>type c:\nate\tuesday001_out.txt
qId     title
38712320        [Partition Benifit on Indexed Column]
38712318        NetBeans does not show MySQL procedures
38712287        How to search a pattern with matching values in MySQL
38712285        Adjust the json response in array and objects
38712109        Getting syntax errors while trying to compile a functiom
38711996        Update Table using Computation from 2 other Tables
38711904        Can I concatenate strings within the prepare() function to insert into specified tables
38711887        Unable to disabled checkbox even after the checkbox status is changed in the database
38711875        Rails inserting incorrect `order` statement
38711794        Save Blob Image with Width &amp;amp; Height VB.Net MySQL

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root -p < C:\nate\tuesday002.sql > C:\nate\tuesday002_out.txt
Enter password: ********

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>type c:\nate\tuesday002_out.txt

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>dir c:\nate\tuesday*.txt
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 1C7C-0B63

 Directory of c:\nate

08/02/2016  02:13 AM               672 tuesday001_out.txt
08/02/2016  02:15 AM                 0 tuesday002_out.txt
               2 File(s)            672 bytes
```

So, it means your input file contained no commands that generated a resultset, as the above clearly shows both test files, and the output.

### Edit

The following only works in interactive mode:

```
mysql --tee="c:\nate\tryThis00J.txt" -h localhost -u root -p
```

which logs interactive commands to a file in append mode. It does **not** work thru command-line redirection unfortunately.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>type \nate\tryThis00j.txt
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 22
Server version: 5.6.31-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use stackoverflow;
Database changed
mysql> create table j2(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> quit
```

Comment: you are right but i want to generate result set like there is a command in the batch file "delete from table where id = 1" and it show on mysql command line "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)", so i want to generate output file with this "Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)" so that i can view that there is no error because in my batch file many procedures are executing and any one of them occur any error then i should be able to read it